# How to select a part of a string with a RegExp and reuse it in a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this RegExp: `var myReg = RegExp("https?://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=[^\"]+","");` to find the youtube link within a string. I then want to make the part of the string matching the RegExp a variable; lets say `var url = "part of string matching the RegExp"`
then I coudl do something like `window.location = url;` to redirect the browser directly to the video page. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to access the first element of the result, if any:

```
var r = string.match(myReg);
if(r) var url = r[0];
```

Take care because is you dont find the url, the result will be a `null` value

Comment: I let you see the full thing, its not working properly look : http://jsfiddle.net/a99Ln/3/

Comment: Your regexp doesnt match the url, it returns a `null` value. I tried with `var myReg = /https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[^"]+/;` and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
myReg.exec(str);
var url = RegExp.lastMatch;
```

Udi

Comment: I let you see the full thing, its not working properly look : http://jsfiddle.net/a99Ln/3/

Comment: it is because the RegExp is not working as you expected. The RegExp evaluation returns null... check your input / RegExp

Comment: the Reg does work, if you try to alert(plainText) on my example it works